# I want to print out the following to the console

Tags: c

I want to print out the following to the console:

```
+++++
++++*
+++**
++***
+****
*****
```

I am a new learner of programming, so encountering some difficulties. Can anyone help me, please? I have tried this, but is incorrect. What do I need to change?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(j=i; j<5; j++){
            for(k=0; k<j; k++){
                printf("*");
            }
            printf("+");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code there, not in the comments.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) printf("%.*s\n", 5, "+++++*****" + i);`

Comment: as with any program the first problem is 'what needs to be done', step by step.  So what needs to be done to output the first line  Then what is different to output the second line ...   Now, there  are a number of ways to actually write the code.   If the arrangement will never change, then code a table that contains the values, then print the table, line by line.  If you want flexibility then pass in the total rows as a parameter. and use loops to output the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea: Use three `for` loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int k = i; k < 5; k++) {
            printf("+");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
+++++
++++*
+++**
++***
+****
*****
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/nZuuHq)

Comment: Or two loops and a ternary: `printf(j < i ? "*" : "+")`

Answer (score 1):

First, generalise it and wrap it in a function. You want a square with a diagonal. It has to be an even number of characters to look right. But + and * could be any character, and the size could be 6 or all the way up to screen maximum width.

so

```
/* print a square with a diagonal
   N - the size of the sides of the square
   cha - character a (eg '+')
   chb - character b (eg '*')
 */      
void printdiagsquare(int N, char cha, char chb);
```

That's our prototype, and that's half the battle.

Now we need to check N is even and positive, then write the loops.

Let's get the test away first.

```
   if(N < 2 || (N % 2) == 1)
     printf(N must be even\n");
```

Now the main loop for each line

```
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
      //printline code here
      printf("\n");
    }
```

Now test it. Is it printing N blank lines?

```
    main(void)
    {
       printdiagsquare(6, '+', '*');
    }
```

Now to get the lines printed.

to print N-1 '+'s is easy. We need j as the counter since i is the outer

```
   for(j=0;j<N-1;j++)
     printf("%c", cha);
```

But we need to generalise, we need to print 6,, 5, 4, 3 and so on as i increases.

```
     So
     for(j=0;j<N-i-1;j++)
       printf("%c", cha);
```

I'll leave the last little bit for you to do. No point just typing ina function blindly.

Comment: OP's problem is to print a 5X6 rectangle, not a square. What is the purpose of the tests for positive and even input, and what do you suggest if the tests fail?

Comment: I miscounted the dots. How to handle errors in C is always an issue. Example edited

Answer (score 1):

You could try more optimized code for **m-rows** and **n-columns** 
 in **2 for loop** only :-

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void) {
        int m = 6; // Rows
        int n = 5; // Cols
        int i,j,k;
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            k = i;       
            for (j = n; j >= 0; j--) {
                if(k>=j)
                printf("*");
                else
                printf("+");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```